# Efficiency of String.equals or STARTS WITH in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Suppose my application scenario is as follows:

Each member of the JOJO family is named after his ancestors. The first generation is called Jonathan, so Jonathan's direct descendants are called JonathanJoseph and JonathanGiorno. And so on, we get JonathanJosephJotaro, JonathanJosephJosuke, JonathanJosephJotaroJolyne.

```
(Jonathan)-[:AncestorOf]->(JonathanJoseph)
(Jonathan)-[:AncestorOf]->(JonathanGiorno)
(JonathanJoseph)-[:AncestorOf]->(JonathanJosephJotaro)
(JonathanJoseph)-[:AncestorOf]->(JonathanJosephJosuke)
(JonathanJosephJotaro)-[:AncestorOf]->(JonathanJosephJotaroJolyne)
```

The JOJO family has inherited the golden spirit from generation to generation, so everyone has a special ability called 'stand power'. However, **we only care about the 'stand power' of the JOJO on the leaf node(which do not have descendants)**.

```
(JonathanGiorno)-[:Owns]->(Gold Experience)
(JonathanJosephJosuke)-[:Owns]->(Crazy Diamond)
(JonathanJosephJotaroJolyne)-[:Owns]->(Stone Free)
```

The question is:

- I want to write queries to get all the names of 'stand power' owned by some family. I think of two solutions

  - Store all ancestor nodes, use String.equals to get the matched ancestor node and then hop to the leaf nodes

    ```
    MATCH (:JOJO{name:"Jonathan"})-[:AncestorOf*]-(:JOJO)-[:Owns]->(sp:StandPower)
    return sp
    ```
  - Not store any ancestor nodes, use START WITH to get the matched leaf nodes

    ```
    MATCH (j:JOJO)-[:Owns]->(sp:StandPower)
    WHERE j.name STARTS WITH "Jonathan"
    return sp
    ```

  Which solution is better?
- In Java, String.equals and String.startsWith have almost same time complexity O(n). So is this still the case in neo4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link on index preference:

> https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/indexes/#_index_preference

Quote:

- TEXT indexes are preferred over BTREE indexes for CONTAINS and ENDS
  WITH.
- BTREE indexes are preferred over TEXT indexes in all other cases.

Unqoute:

Thus, on your example I will go with

```
MATCH (:JOJO{name:"Jonathan"})-[:AncestorOf*]-(:JOJO)-[:Owns]->(sp:StandPower)
return sp
```

In general, doing a string match will out perform STARTS WITH since the former is already utilizing the index.  Much better if you do a query plan to see the details on how the indices are being used.